# Need help for Indian visa Entry Refused issue

Tags: india, bangladeshi-citizens

I am Bangladeshi and I came to India on a student visa.

First I was admitted to college 1. I was new at that time and I didn't know about the official process. I asked college authority about FRRO (Foreigner Registration) and they told they would handle everything, but they didn't apply for FRRO registration.

I then decided to change to college 2 and learned that my FRRO wasn't complete. I informed college 2 about my problem and they told they would take care of it. I went on to college 2 without FRRO registration. I asked college 2 about what to do and they told me that when my visa expires, they would apply for an exit permission. I'd return to my country, get a new visa, and join the college again.

For this reason I waited and when I applied for exit permission they asked for a police clearance, which requires an NOC (no objection certificate) from college 1. When I asked for the NOC, college 1 demanded a huge amount of money, which I didn't have. When I finally convinced college 1 to give me an NOC, I had already overstayed.

I got an exit permission from Hyderabad FRRO and returned to Bangladesh. I applied and received a new visa. But when I went to the Benapole immigration, the immigration officer told me because of overstaying before, they were not able to permit me to enter India and they gave an Entry Refused seal in my passport.

So what can I do now? Currently I am in 3rd year and my whole career is in danger. Please give me good advice for solving the problem.

Comment: Your situation seems too complex to rely upon opinions from people you don't know on the internet. I suggest that you consult with an Advocate (as lawyers and solicitors are known in India) who has sat and passed the All India Bar Examination (AIBE), and who has been entered onto the Roll (e.g., "list") of Advocates in India. Stay away from non-licensed "advisors" whose knowledge and ethics are repeatedly impugned in both Travel.SE and Expatriates.SE.